# Unable to add new users to my database through Django registration form

Tags: django, forms, registration, superuser

The code works well but when trying to add a new user to the site it logs in as the superuser only.

Model

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label = 'Username', max_length = 30)
    first_name = forms.CharField(label = 'First name', max_length = 30,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'Name'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(label = 'Last name', max_length = 30,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'Name'}))
    email1 = forms.EmailField(label = 'email', required = True,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'email'}))
    email2 = forms.EmailField(label = 'Re-enter email',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'email'}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(label= "Password", widget = forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class' : 'password1'}))
    birthday = forms.DateField(label = 'Birthday',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'birthday'}))
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1','password2')

    def save(self, commit = True):
        user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit = False)
        user.email1 = self.cleaned_data['email1']
        user.email2 = self.cleaned_data['email2']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.birthday = self.cleaned_data['birthday']
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user

    def clean_username(self):
        email1 = self.cleaned_data['email1']
        if not re.search(r"(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)", email1):
            raise forms.ValidationError('Use a real email address eg. something@example.com.')
            try:
                user.objects.get(email1 = email1)
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                return username
            raise forms.ValidationError('email is already in use.')

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.clean_data['username']
        if not re.search(r'^\w+$', username):
            raise forms.ValidationError('Username can only contain alphanumeric characters and the underscore.')
        try:
            user.objects.get(username = username)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return username
        raise forms.ValidationError('Username is already taken.')
```

Views

```
def register_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            user = User.objects.create_user(
                username = form.clean_data['username'],
                password = form.clean_data['password1'],
                email = form.clean_data['email']
            )
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/register/success/')
    else:
        args = {}
        args.update(csrf(request))
        args['form'] = RegistrationForm()
        print(args)

    return render(request, 'registration/register.html', args)
```

Comment: "When trying to add a new user to the site it logs in as the superuser only". Can you clarify what you mean by that?

Comment: You seem to be creating the User twice: once in the form save method, and once in the view.

Comment: It redirects to the admin users page without saving the new user into the db